# Dart avait Future, postpone just certain line of code and execute the rest

Tags: dart, async-await, future

Want to have certain lines of code postponed, using await Future for it and it works great, problem is that it postpones all the code after it, I need it to postpone just certain line of code while continuing to execute rest of the code imediately

```
void main() async {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    //postpone just next line or few lines of code
    print('postpone this line of code ${i + 1}');
    print('postpone me too');
  }
  //should execute without being postponed
  print('continue imediately without being postponed by await Future');
}
```

Is this possible with await Future or with some other function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`await` it syntactic sugar for registering a `Future.then` callback.  The point of using `await` is to make it easier to make all of the subsequent code wait for the `Future` to complete.  If that's not what you want, you can use `Future.then` directly:

```dart
void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
      print('postpone this line of code ${i + 1}');
      print('postpone me too');
    });
  }
  print('continue immediately without being postponed by await Future');
}
```

Since `Future.delayed` takes a callback, you can also skip the `then` completely:

```dart
void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('postpone this line of code ${i + 1}');
      print('postpone me too');
    });
  }
  print('continue immediately without being postponed by await Future');
}
```

If you don't use the created future for anything, this is equivalent to using a `Timer`:

```dart
import 'dart:async' show Timer;
void main() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      print('postpone this line of code ${i + 1}');
      print('postpone me too');
    });
  }
  print('continue immediately without being postponed by await Future');
}
```